# Linux/BusyBox multimedia Server

Tags: linux, open-source, busybox, multimedia

I bought an EMTEC Movie Cube Q8000 some years ago. Now it has no use, and I have recently realize I can use it as multimedia server. It is a Linux/BusyBox system. I changed a file so now the NAS mode is constantly on. I would like to access that server from Google Chrome on my PC, so I want to know which is the file that is run when I write the IP address from my PC. I mean, I want to manage the files in my server from Google Chrome (I would have to write an HTML file, the thing is I don't know where is it supposed to be located on in the server). Also if it is possible to delete TV options and all that staff Movie Cube had installed defaultly (so I have more space in the hard disk).

Fill free to ask anything you need to know, and sorry for my bad English, I'm not an English speaker ^^

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, when you access the Q8000 via Google Chrome? When you say 'multimedia server', do you mean a fileserver, or something different?

Comment: I mean, i want to see an HTML file where my files in the server appear. So i need to locate the HTML file in the server i dont know where, and connect it to the server

Comment: Do you mean that you access an HTML file via eg Chrome and it shows you the files currently present on the server?

Comment: hm.... maybe? I type my ip address in the Chrome and an HTML file is opened, where i can see the files currently present on the server

Comment: Can you access the Linux system console?  Check if any webserver program is already executing.  From a PC web browser, try to access the webserver by typing in the device's IP address or hostname.  *"Also if it is possible to delete TV options and all that staff Movie Cube had installed "* -- Are you sure this is on the HDD, or is it in flash within the device itself?